# I can not save data to sql in loop - python

Tags: python, sql

im trying to put data to sql table but there is always blank file. 
when i comment Insert, and print data on the screen then i see everything.
Can anyone help me?

```
import csv, sqlite3
#filename = "data_.csv"
#f = open(filename, "w")
qlite_file = 'my_first_db.sqlite.db'  
con = sqlite3.connect("tedsddwwsssat.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (var0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13, var14, var15);")
    for a in range(1,10):
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    my_url = 'https://www.auto-data.net/en/?f=showCar&car_id='+ str(a)
    try:
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close();
        page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
        container = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"carData rightT"})
        x = container[0].findAll("tr")
        xxx = len(x)
        print(xxx)
        #if xxx>15:
        #   xxx=15
        if x[0].findAll("td")[1].text in ("Nissan ","volkswagen ","AC ", "BMW ", "Citroen ", "Seat ", "Toyota ", "Tesla", "Volvo ", "Jeep ", "Kia ", "Renault", "Fiat ", "Ford ", "Mercedes-Benz "):
            for xx in range(10):
                x1 = x[xx].findAll("td")[0].text
                x2 = x[xx].findAll("td")[1].text
                put = print("var"+str(xx))
                print(x2)
                #cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (?) VALUES (?)", (put, x2))

            con.commit()    
            #f.write(x1 + ": " + x2 + ",")
        f.write("\n")
    except:
        pass
    #print("done " + str(a))
con.close()
```

Comment: you use `except: pass` so you can't see error message - and this is why `except: pass` is the worst solution for exceptions. You should at least display error `except Exception as e: print(e)` (PL: nie używaj `except: pass`)

Comment: Now i can see syntax error with cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (?) VALUES (?)", (str(put), x2))

Comment: as @creativecoding said - `print` is used only to send text on screen. It returns nothing. So you need `put = "var" + str(xx)`

Comment: I know that, but `put = "var" + str(xx)` still doesnt work for me.
`near "?": syntax error`

Comment: as I know `(?)` doesn't works for column names (and table names) - it works only for values. You will have to use string formating to create query with column name `"INSERT INTO t ({0}) VALUES (?)".format(put)` and then you can use it in `executemany`

Comment: OMG it works. The last problem i've got is that every char is in new row
https://scr.hu/ry16rR

Comment: probably somewhere you use `for` loop but you should't. I would have to run it to see how it works

Comment: Maybe I have it - `executemany` as second argument needs tuple but `(x2)` is not tuple. It's single string but Python can treats string as tuple with many elements - every char is one element in tuple. You have to use `,` to create tuple - `(x2, )`

Comment: PERFECT :) thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `print` function is `None`. `None` is assigned to the variable `put`. You probably want to change this line:

```
put = print("var"+str(xx))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made own version

Because there is variable number of columns (and "varX")
so SQL query needs variable number of `?` - ie. `(?,?,?)` for three columns

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("tedsddwwsssat.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (var0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13, var14, var15);")

for car_id in range(1, 10):
    my_url = 'https://www.auto-data.net/en/?f=showCar&car_id=' + str(car_id)
    try:
        page_html = urlopen(my_url).read()

        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        container = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"carData rightT"})

        all_trs = container[0].findAll("tr")
        first_td = all_trs[0].findAll("td")[1]

        if first_td.text in ("Nissan ", "volkswagen ", "AC ", "BMW ", "Citroen ", "Seat ", "Toyota ", "Tesla", "Volvo ", "Jeep ", "Kia ", "Renault", "Fiat ", "Ford ", "Mercedes-Benz "):
            # first get all values and column names
            columns = []
            values = []

            for x in range(10):
                columns.append("var" + str(x))
                values.append(all_trs[x].findAll("td")[1].text)
            print(columns)
            print(values)

            # there is variable number of columns
            # so you have to create string with variable number of `?'
            qmarks = ','.join(['?']*len(columns))            
            columns = ','.join(columns)

            # put all columns in one row using one INSERT
            query = "INSERT INTO t ({}) VALUES ({})".format(columns, qmarks)
            cur.execute(query, values)
            con.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

con.close()
```